# Near field and far field EMI

Tags: voltage, current, emc, electromagnetic, microwave

I was reading [this](https://incompliancemag.com/article/near-and-far-fields-simplified-for-emiemc/) article on EMI near field vs far field.

I am confused on how the Electric field and Magnetic field are separate within the near field and suddenly after a certain distance, these two fields combine and become EM field that can be measured in far field.

How do those Electric and magnetic field don't combine in the near field itself?

Why does it have to wait for a certain distance for those fields to combine and become EM waves?

Comment: I think you mix things up, the Electric and Magnetic fields don't "know" if they're "near field" or "far field". The near/far separation is just a way for us humans to look at the behavior of fields. So an EM wave physically doesn't change behavior (I mean, how could it?), the far/near behavior is a **simplification** for us humand to understand and explain the behavior more easily. Have you read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near_and_far_field ?

Comment: Thank you. So, the behaviour of the fields don't change with respect to the distance of measurement from the source? Then, why do we need to understand their behaviour at near field and far field?

Comment: Read my comment carefully. Indeed the fields don't change their behavior. But the behavior of an EM field, if you would want to understand on a **detailed level**, would become **very complex**. So we **simplify**. We have 1) a "near field" behavior and we have 2) a "far field" behavior. In practice, the "far field" behavior is what is usually the most important.

Comment: One **example** of "far field" behavior is ignoring that an antenna has a certain size. Instead we simplify and assume that the antenna is just a **point** that emits all EM power. That makes things easier to calculate.

Comment: Oh thank you. So, the near field behavior assumes that the antenna has a certain size?

Comment: *So, the near field behavior assumes that the antenna has a certain size?* No, read the Wikipedia page carefully especially what it says about antennas. In the near field situation, we have to take the antenna's size into account (there is no "assumes that the antenna has a certain size", the antenna has a size and that is used, there is no assumption). In the far field approach we don't have to consider the size of the antenna.

Comment: Yes, I am reading the wiki page. But why we need to separate the behaviour into near and far fields? What benefit it does to us?

Comment: My understanding, and I'm not an 'antenna engineer', is that in the 'near field', the E-mag waves are curved.  But if you get far enough away from a source, the waves effectively become planar.  At whatever point the waves become flat enough to ignore their curvature, you are in 'far field'.    Basically it's easier to make calculations and predictions when the waves are 'flat'.

Comment: Oh Ok, But I need to understand what is curved and what is flat now

Comment: *But why we need to separate the behaviour into near and far fields?* You really need to read more carefully as I already explained this in the comments above. The keyword is **simplify**.

Comment: @Newbie  "Curved" and "Flat" don't mean anything complex.  I literally mean 'curved' like the surface of a ball, or 'flat' like a piece of paper.  $$$$  Do this thought experiment...  $$$$  Suppose you are standing by a really big lake, couple miles (kilometer) across.  Suppose also that lake has NO WAVES... perfectly calm & flat....   Drop a stone in the water, you will see circular waves move away from that point, yes???  Now imagine you are on the far side of the lake, 2 miles away.  When those waves finally reach you, they have stretched out so much they are effectively straight lines.

Comment: @KyleB, thank you very much for the analogy. Really appreciate it. I have these questions. In the near field, the EM waves also still exist right? But why do we measure E field and H field separately using those dedicated oscilloscope probes?

Answer (score 1):

These formulas are for a "linear wire antenna" ...

from the book "ANTENNA THEORY ANALYSIS AND DESIGN" ... Constantine A. Balanis

One can see that there are terms in 1/r, 1/ r^2, 1/r^3.
These are effective nearest antenna.

When distance increase, some terms vanish quickly and only the terms in 1/r are effective.
They are the "far" field terms.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

E & H fields are transverse to the direction of travel but attenuate inversely squared with distance = \$k/d^2\$. This is due to the product of the gain of the Rx and Tx each having a 1/d relationship. This product is 20 dB per decade in distance for wavelength.  Thus, the shorter the wavelength, the greater the loss. [This is defined by Friis Loss](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free-space_path_loss).

But this Friis Loss results in errors of predicting near field loss as you get closer than 1 wavelength.

Why?

Then the signal begins to rise 60 dB / decade towards touching as the far-field point source becomes a 3D aperture for each side coupling the other or \$k/d^6\$ product attenuation effects.

So the border line depends on the aperture product changes with distance or the effective beamwidth coupling each antenna that determines this boundary condition that is defined by one (1) wavelength.

[ref](https://m.eet.com/media/1140931/19213-150828.pdf)

Comment: The distinction between "near field" and "far field" is due to the manner of decreasing electric and magnetic fields. In the vicinity of the antenna, there are fields which decrease in 1 / r ^ 3 and 1 / r ^ 2 then in 1 / r ... where they become distant ... and this over a distance of about the wavelength ... unless I'm mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

This can be explained from Maxwell's equations:
$$\nabla \times E = -\frac{\partial B}{\partial t}$$
$$\nabla \times H = \frac{\partial D}{\partial t} + J$$
$$\nabla.D = \rho$$
$$\nabla.B=0$$
These are, in general, coupled equations in electric and magnetic fields, where the coupling terms are the time derivative of electric and magnetic fields. Without these time derivates the fields can be treated independently.
Since spatial derivatives of fields are inversely related to the distance from source, the left terms in the equations are going to be much bigger than the time derivative terms for small distances from source. For these sufficiently small distances, these time derivative terms can be neglected. And hence the electric and magnetic fields can be treated independently. This region is known as the near field region.
For larger distances the time derivatives are not negligible and hence the fields need to be treated together.